# Table css format

Tags: html, css

```
#table1
{
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  margin-right:80px
}

table,th,td{
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-right:80px
}
```

i am using 2 different types of table,with 2 different color, but whenever i try to put `th,td` in anyone of the table,all the tables get same color as that of `th,td` table.

how to customize each table?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code as well?

Comment: @Shashank : i don't want to sound rude...but have you ever heard of word => **formatting** ??

Comment: *whenever i try to put th,td in anyone of the table* — How are you doing this? Show us your attempt, then we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SAMPLE TABLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gDZC5/)

```
<table class="mytable"></table>

.mytable, mytable.th, mytable.td
{
 //some codes
}

<table id="table1"></table>
#table1
{
//some codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follow

```
//css

        .table1{
           //table1 style
        }
        .table1 th{
        //th style for table1 class
        }
        .table1 td{
        //set color for table1
        }

        .table2{
        }
        .table2 th{
        //set your color
        }
        .table2 td{
        //set color for table1
        }

    //html code

        <table class="table1">
        <tr>
          <th>...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="table2">
        <tr>
          <th>.... </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```